# Clamp RotateAround object Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I am making a script to rotate my camera around a sphere but I need to clamp the y axis so the camera does not co over the polls of the sphere I am using rotate around to move my camera.

Thanks!

My current code

```
public float sensitivity = 1;
public float moveSpeed = 10;
public float maxUp = 45f;
public float maxDown = -45f;

public Transform target;

void Update()
{
    transform.LookAt(target);

    float HorizontalAxis = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;
    float VerticalAxis = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * moveSpeed;

    if (HorizontalAxis >= 1 || VerticalAxis >= 1 || HorizontalAxis <= -1 || VerticalAxis <= -1)
    {
        Quaternion targetPos = transform.rotation;
        targetPos.x += HorizontalAxis * sensitivity;
        targetPos.y += VerticalAxis * sensitivity;

        transform.RotateAround(target.position, Vector3.left, targetPos.y);
        transform.RotateAround(target.position, Vector3.up, targetPos.x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes no sense to begin with.

You do

```
Quaternion targetPos = transform.rotation;
    targetPos.x += HorizontalAxis * sensitivity;
    targetPos.y += VerticalAxis * sensitivity;
```

Just to then use these as parameters in

```
 transform.RotateAround(target.position, Vector3.left, targetPos.y);
 transform.RotateAround(target.position, Vector3.up, targetPos.x);
```

A [`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) has not three but four components `x`, `y`, `z` **and `w`** and they move in ranges between `-1` and `1`. You **never** touch the individual component of a `Quaternion` except you really know exactly what you are doing!

You rather simply want to use the `HorizontalAxis` and `VerticalAxis` directly as the parameters to `RotateAround`.

---

You could rather simply remember and clamp how much you already rotated like e.g.

```
private float rotatedY;

private void Update()
{
    transform.LookAt(target);

    // why two different multipliers anyway though?
    var HorizontalAxis = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed * sensitivity;
    var VerticalAxis = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * moveSpeed * sensitivity;

    // would a positive rotation exceed the maxUp?
    if(rotatedY + VerticalAxis > maxUp)
    {
        // then rotate only so much that you terminate exactly on maxUp
        VerticalAxis = maxUp - rotatedY;
    }
    // would a negative rotation exceed the maxDown?
    else if(rotatedY + VerticalAxis < maxDown)
    {
        // then you rotate only that much that you terminate exactly on maxDown
        VerticalAxis = maxDown - rotatedY;
    }
    
    transform.RotateAround(target.position, Vector3.left, VerticalAxis);
    transform.RotateAround(target.position, Vector3.up, HorizontalAxis);

    // sum up how much you already rotated vertically
    rotatedY += VerticalAxis;
}
```

Comment: That works great but when I rotate on the y axis the movement is slightly diagonal do you know how to make this stop? Also thanks for your help.